# .Fortran() returns no result

Tags: r, fortran

In R, when i tried the following code

```
.Fortran("add", x= as.double(2),y= as.double(3))
```

R returned only the arguments but no result!

```
$x
[1] 2
$y
[1] 3
```

`add` is the only simple function i written in the Fortran source file test.f90:

```
function add (x,y) result (f_result)  
real:: x,y,f_result   
f_result = x+y   
end  function add
```

and I used:

```
gfortran -shared -o test.dll test.f90
```

to obtain the `test.dll` which was loaded into R by

```
dyn.load("test.dll")
```

In all above processes, I got no error or warning message. So I just cannot figure out where the problem is. I searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. Any help?

By the way, I use windows7(x86), R3.0.2, GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.7.0

Comment: From [Writing R Extentions, Section 5.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran), "Note that the compiled code should not return anything except through its arguments: C functions should be of type void and FORTRAN subprograms should be subroutines."

Comment: Also post add function

Answer (score 2):

Write a subroutine, use an argument as a return value:

```
  subroutine add(x,y,z)
  real*8 x,y,z
  z=x+y
  end
```

Compile like this:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB add.f

> dyn.load("add.so")
> .Fortran("add",as.double(1),as.double(2),as.double(-999))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

You don't even need to name the arguments, but it helps since you can then get the return value by name:

```
> .Fortran("add",as.double(1),as.double(2),ans=as.double(-999))$ans
[1] 3
>
```